# How to save credit card for later use in Stripe payment with Flutter app and Firebase?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

What is the approach to this problem? Can I do everything from app or I need to use cloud functions to save/get saved card?

Answer (score 3):

Both "saving card for later use" [0] and "get saved card" [1] are both secret-key operations only, so those should be driven from your server-side code / cloud function.

The publishable key (the API key you use in your Flutter app) isn't capable of fetching/attaching saved cards to Customer objects, in Stripe. You can imagine the security concern if this were supported, that someone could use your publishable key (it is a public key) to list another Customer's saved cards.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list

Comment: If I type my card details first time, how does stripe know my card details next time?

Comment: Your backend determines that. Say I come to your app, your server-side code creates a Customer object (e.g. cus_123) representing me and attach pm_123 as a card to me. The next time I come to your app, you recognize that cus_123 is back and you show me my list of cards, e.g. pm_123. So your backend has to track this association of user<>Customer object.

Comment: Thank you so much. The thing is, I am not sure in things like this because I don't know if that flow is security risk. I am a bit disappointed in stripe docs. They are so precise that in start I didn't have idea how things work in a nutshell. In global I would prefer them but it's silly to not have this a bit simplified in official docs.

Comment: which flow are you worried about being a security risk? I didn't fully understand

Comment: I didn't know what identifier I can save on my backend. I thought that this pm_id can't be stored on my backend and that it needs to go strictly through stripe.

Comment: The raw card details shouldn't be touching your backend. The PaymentMethods ID is a tokenized representation of a card and is OK to save on your backend.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the document you are looking for: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

1. Create a Customer before setup
2. Create a SetupIntent
3. Collect card details
4. Charge the saved card later

Answer (score -7):

Use shared Preferences? You can learn more about it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Comment: Are you joking? Shared references are the playground in rooted devices. You don't need someone to steal your card details.